# SQL: Check existence of a file on local machine when i'm connected to another database server

Tags: sql-server, file-exists

I have two test Machines. i don't know if this is possible but here is what im trying to do

1. Machine1: has DBServer setup

   where i am currently logged in

   where the file C:\test_IDNumber1.txt is located

   where i use SSMS. i connect to Machine2\SQLServer
2. Machine2: has DBServer setup

   where the dbserver for DBTest is located

   DBTest is where the Filename records are stored
3. First i need to do some select script from DBTest to get the IDNumber for the Filename

   ```
   SELECT FileName FROM tblFiles where...... (results to "IDNumber1")
   ```
4. Then i'll check the existence of the file with the same IDNumber (e.g: "C:\test_IDNumber1.txt") using this script

   ```
   EXEC xp_fileexist 'C:\test_IDNumber1.txt', @exists OUTPUT
   ```
5. If the file exists, i need to delete the record from DBtest on Machine2 and the file from Machine1

   ```
   DELETE FROM tblFiles where Filename = 'IDNumber1'
   EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'del ''C:\test_IDNumber1.txt'''
   ```

but the result for existence is always 0 because it is checking the C drive of Machine2 where the DBTest is located.

Is there a way to use a select script from a db from Machine2 and check the existence of a file from Machine1?

thank you very much

Comment: Why database server needs to check for the file on the remote machine? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @miroxlav , the filename of the file i am trying to check is from the database. i need to first select the idnumber from the database then check if the file with filename same as idnumber exists

Comment: Is it viable for you to set up SQL Server at Machine1 and from DBTest on Machine2 execute stored procedure on Machine1 SQL Server  which will inform you about the existence of the file?

Comment: i apologize @miroxlav im not sure i understood you correctly, right now i am using sqlserver2012 on Machine1 and i am connected to dbserver which is located on Machine2. i am running the script on Machine1, is that the same as you suggested?

Comment: hi @miroxlav, i tried my best to rephrase, i hope the edits will be clearer

Comment: Please explain further - if the file exists what then? do you want to import it? You could write a batch file that runs locally that probably does what you want.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i need to delete the file if it exists

Comment: @miroxlav hope the new edits are clear. the bottom line is, the database is on Machine2 and the file is on Machine1. I want to delete the file from Machine1 where the filename is in the database is selected from database from Machine2

Comment: You can write a script that runs on the client machine that does this. It's more difficult to write a scirpt on the SQL Server because you need to give it access to all the client machines

Answer (score 0):

Several possible solutions can exist. One of the least expensive is:

1. Make file storage on Machine1 shared, visible to Machine2 and mapped there as network drive (e.g. `Z:`) with read+delete permissions.

   Machine1: `C:\Shared\`   (mapping)→   Machine2: `Z:\`
2. Then you can use SQL commands similar to what you already show in steps **4** and **5** in order to test the existence of `Z:\test_IDNumber1.txt` and delete the file.

Comment: Why map when you can UNC?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid – I originally thought about UNC but I was not sure whether it works. I found it should so you are right, this can be better.